# Google webmaster International targeting "United States" will it work for SEO?

Tags: google-search-console, traffic, internationalization, geotargeting

I have started a brand new website. Basically, It will be product review base website. I will promote Amazon products on that website.

After little experiment, I have found that, if US people buy 15 products then rest of the world people buy only 1 product(mainly the UK).

This is not the real data. Just got it after little experiment don't know what is happening with other. Or my review product might be more useful for the US than other country.

Thus, I want to target only people in the US. That means from Google Webmaster Tool I want to set up "International Targeting" only United States.

Will that increase my website rank for the US in Google?  If so, reducing ranks in other countries is not a problem.  I want to increase rankings in the US.

Comment: I am not sure if it will take the desired effect, or if it will worth the time but I am sure that AdWords campaign targeting U.S. would be much of a help for you.

Comment: Yes, paid campaign might work but I want to target natural traffic and it is only possible through seo. Thus, i need to know if any positive improvement occur by selecting "International Targeting" United States.

Comment: It is possible but I am lacking facts for it, altought have you think about an ad in the related search results, this kind of ads usually gain the best of the organic traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will that increase my website rank for the US in Google?

Yes, because US people do better CTR on SERP and more conversions on your own site.

**Case 1**
imagine: your site offers a service for US residents. They are very interesting in it, and, if they see your site's snippet in SERP, they click it wildly. But your site isn't limited to visitors from US. And visitors from i.e. India, looking for such service in google.com, see in SERP your site's snippet wildly too. But then, if they come to your site, the see, the service is only for US residents, and they bounce. Google realizes the big amount of bouncers and thinks, aha, some people bounce, do they probably mean, this site as a kind of shit...? High bounce rate will cause lowering of relevancy.

**Case 2**
imagine the same: your site offers a service for US residents. You say it definitely in the site's description, so this information appears in your site's SERP snippet. Visitors, form, i.e. India, are looking for such service, but they don't click your site in SERP, because they read "aha, this service is only for us residents". On this way your site gets lower SERP CTR and, following lower relevancy.

**Case 3**
Your site offers a service for US residents. You say it definitely in the site's description, so this information appears in your site's SERP snippet. But additionally you limit the audience of your site to US. Google then shows your site only to US residents - the amount of visitors ramains pretty the same, but on this way your site gets much higher SERP CTR and much lower bounce rate. Both will result in higher relevancy.

Answer (score 0):

It will surely boost ranking as google prefer to show the local links. The boost will be in www.google.com (US) however you wont be able to see much in other countries. 
"Users comes from other countries and see the page as irrelevant and increase bounce rate" This will happen anyway, currently if you have marked it as international site and anyone from other countries will still be leaving site early and contributing to towards bounce rate. If you mark your site as US local the Google will show you higher in US and keeps you lower in other location, the benefit? You will get lesser traffic from other locations which leads to lesser bounce rate.